Finding RDBMS table relationships using SqlConnection schemas
I am writing an app in .NET 8 and using the Northwind database to generate stored-procedures, entity POCO classes, stored-procedure wrappers, controllers, etc.
Database Relationship Diagram:

In order to determine relationships between tables, I am querying the Schema as follows:
using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
await connection.OpenAsync();
var schemaTables = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("Tables");
var schemaColumns = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("Columns");
var schemaForeignKeys = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("ForeignKeys");
var schemaIndexes = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("Indexes");
var schemaXXX = await connection.GetSchemaAsync("XXX");
/* Process [schemaXXX]... */

While I am able to create tables, columns, etc., the ForeignKeys schema does not appear to have both ends of a relationship. Consider the following results:
Schema: ForeignKeys

Schema: Indexes

How could I get something like the following:
TYPE        PRINCIPLE       DEPENDENT
OneToMany   Department.Id   Employee.DepartmentId
OneToMany   Employee.Id     Employee.ReportsTo

Please note that I am not interested in a database-first approach or EntityFramework or other ORMs. I need to generate the entity POCO classes myself using SqlConnection.GetSchema.
I am also considering using SQL Server Management Objects eventually, but am stuck with ADO .NET for the moment.

I've not added this as a full answer as it doesn't meet your constraints (using ADO.NET). However, if the opportunity arises, a powerful alternative approach is using DACPAC interrogation. NorthWind is meant to be used with SSDT; when building an SSDT project in Visual Studio it will output a DACPAC. There's a special SSDT library which can be used to interrogate everything, including both sides of an FK relationship. We generate all POCOs; DTOs; service layer; OpenAPI info; then, by derivation, WPF client views; all using Roslyn source generators which at their core hook into the DACPAC.

As can be read in documentation for SQL Server Schema Collections, there is no info you are looking for.
Instead, you can use raw query to get that information. There's this SO post guiding how to do that, based on this SQL Essentials: Foreign Key Metadata: Improving on INFORMATION_SCHEMA Views
SELECT 
     KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
   , KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS 'FK_TABLE_NAME'
   , KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS 'FK_COLUMN_NAME'
   , KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'FK_ORDINAL_POSITION'
   , KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'UQ_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
   , KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS 'UQ_TABLE_NAME'
   , KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS 'UQ_COLUMN_NAME'
   , KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'UQ_ORDINAL_POSITION'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1
ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2
ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
   AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION

C# code snippet:
using var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

var query = @"SELECT 
     KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'FK_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
   , KCU1.TABLE_NAME AS 'FK_TABLE_NAME'
   , KCU1.COLUMN_NAME AS 'FK_COLUMN_NAME'
   , KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'FK_ORDINAL_POSITION'
   , KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME AS 'UQ_CONSTRAINT_NAME'
   , KCU2.TABLE_NAME AS 'UQ_TABLE_NAME'
   , KCU2.COLUMN_NAME AS 'UQ_COLUMN_NAME'
   , KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION AS 'UQ_ORDINAL_POSITION'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS RC
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU1
ON KCU1.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = RC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU1.CONSTRAINT_NAME = RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME
JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE KCU2
ON KCU2.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG 
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
   AND KCU2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = 
RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME
   AND KCU2.ORDINAL_POSITION = KCU1.ORDINAL_POSITION";

using var command = connection.CreateCommand();

command.CommandText = query;
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while(reader.Read())
{
    
}


Thank you! This saved me from having to shift to SMO prematurely. It would also be interesting to explore what EntityFramework database-first generators use for querying RDBMS structures.

INFORMATION_SCHEMA should be avoided on SQL Server, it's for compatibility only and has issues. Better to use sys.tables etc.

@Charlieface: Thanks. Could you link to MS documentation that states the same? It would help me track down alternative paths.

@RaheelKhan From the docs: "Information schema views enable applications to work correctly although significant changes have been made to the underlying system tables. The information schema views included in SQL Server comply with the ISO standard definition for the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Important: Some changes have been made to the information schema views that break backward compatibility. These changes are described in the topics for the specific views." See also https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views
